# Vba code to create a pivot table and then filter by value top 10

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I have some code which will create a pivot table how I would like it butwhen I try to add a pivot filter to filter the top ten values I get an error:

"Runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error"

```
Sub Create_Port_Pivots(dataField, PivotLastRow, tableDest, counter)
        '
        ' Creates pivot table on Pivot sheet
        ' Author: Daryl Findlay (dfind)
        '
        Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

        ' Select the source sheet and assign LastRow & LastCol
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Select
        LastRow = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
        LastCol = Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column

        ' Create the PivotTable object.
        Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            sourceData:=ActiveSheet.Name & "!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastCol, _
            TableDestination:="Pivot!R" & PivotLastRow & tableDest, _
            TableName:="Pivot" & counter)

        ' Specify row and column fields.
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Date")
        objField.Orientation = xlRowField
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Time Group")
        objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Port Name")
        objField.Orientation = xlRowField

        ' Specify a data field with its summary.
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields(dataField)
        objField.Orientation = xlDataField
        objField.Function = xlAverage
        ' -----------------  Filter by top 10 - Error with second param
        objField.PivotFilters.Add xlTopCount, objTable.PivotFields("Port Name"), 10

 End Sub
```

The debug highlights this line as the problem:

```
objField.PivotFilters.Add xlTopCount, objTable.PivotFields("Port Name"), 10
```

I think the issue may be with the second param of that function call. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to a colleague I have discovered another method to do this.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot" & counter).PivotFields("Port Name").AutoShow xlAutomatic _
        , xlTop, 10, "Average of Max I/O /sec"
```

Replace `objField.PivotFilters.Add xlTopCount, objTable.PivotFields("Port Name"), 10` with the above line of code and it will show only the top 10 values